# Bathroom light switch inoperative, but fan swith okay

Tags: electrical

My light switch in the bathroom just stopped working, but the switch right next to it for the vent is okay. The light switch turns on an array of six bulbs and I checked them and they seem fine. All other electrical switches in the house work. I opened up and looked in the housing and nothing seems out of he ordinary. Any ideas what could be going on?

Comment: Old style standard switches have two screws on the right side, visible if you remove the cover plate. You don't have to remove or even loosen the switch. When the switch is OFF only one screw is hot, but when the switch is ON both are hot. If you have a voltmeter you can check for 120 V at each screw relative to a ground. If you don't have a receptacle nearby, you can get a ground by plugging an extension cord into a convenient receptacle and then using the ground in the plug end. If the switch is not making contact internally when it is turned ON, then there would be 120 V only on one screw.

Comment: @JimStewart For this job a [voltage detector](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Milwaukee-Voltage-Detector-2200-20/203168523) would probably be the better tool. Put it next to the wire and it will tell you if it's hot.

Comment: I agree with Jim Stewart a non contact tester may show voltage with the switch in the off position due to induced voltage from the hot leg.  Jim that should be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Old style standard switches have two screws on the right side, visible if you remove the cover plate. You don't have to remove or even loosen the switch. When the switch is OFF only one screw is hot, but when the switch is ON both are hot. If you have a voltmeter you can check for 120 V at each screw relative to a ground. If you don't have a receptacle nearby, you can get a ground by plugging an extension cord into a convenient receptacle and then using the ground in the plug end. If the switch is not making contact internally when it is turned ON, then there would be 120 V to ground (or neutral) only on one screw.

If you have a 3-way switch or one of the new powered switches, it's more complicated.

Comment: With a voltmeter probe it is easier to make contact with the neutral in a plug than with the ground. Going to neutral will work for testing for voltage.